# select multiple records from postgresql DB and insert to another table using WSO2ESB

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-esb

we are trying to perform DB operation like Select and Insert. first we try to fetch the data from a table from Mysql datasource and next step is to insert the data we fetched to another table which is in Postgre datasource. Tried DBlookup mediator in WSO2ESB to fetch records but received only one record while executing select statement. following is the code tried to fetch data from MySQl.

```
<dblookup>
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <password/>
            <driver/>
            <url/>
            <user/>
        </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
        <sql><![CDATA[select <col1> as <aliasname1>,<col2> as <aliasname2> from <tablename>]]></sql>
        <result column="aliasname1" name="aliasname1"/>
        <result column="aliasname2" name="aliasname2"/>
    </statement>
</dblookup>
<log>
    <property expression="get-property('aliasname1')" name="Return aliasname1"/>
    <property expression="get-property('aliasname2')" name="Return aliasname2"/>
</log>
```

but we are receiving 1 record details. request you to guide me how to fetch all records from table and based on that how to insert the same no.of records to another table.

Answer (score 0):

The DBLookup mediator can set a property from one row in a result set. It cannot return multiple rows.

If you are using WSO2 EI then its better to use Data services.

Comment: Basanagouda thanks for the comment. we have tried DSS we are able to fetch records as well. we are calling the DSS in ESB for processing records but we are unable to process the data using iterator mediator. following is the sample payload we received  {"Entries":{"Entry":[{"name":"abc","addr":"100BGR"},{"name":"def","addr":"101BGR"}]}}. how we can extract name and addr from this payload in ESB

Comment: we are able to log the data we receive from DSS. To process each records we tried following code in iterate mediator,`<iterate continueParent="true" expression="//Entries/Entry" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
<target><sequence><log><property expression="//Entries/Entry/name" name="Name is"/><property expression="//Entries/Entry/addr" name="Address is"/></log></sequence></target></iterate>`. but we are not able to extract data request you to guide me how to process the data